# How do you use the jQuery contains function with object variables?

Tags: object, contains

I know this works:

```
var $object = $('*:contains("I am a simple string")');
```

So why doesn't this work as well?

```
var $object = $someObject:contains("I am a simple string");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's syntactically invalid JavaScript. Even if you change the `:` to a `.` in the second case, [there is no `.contains()` method](http://api.jquery.com/contains/), so I think this is what you intend:

```
var $object = $someObject.find('*:contains("I am a simple string")');
```